# Visual studio style error "sa1505"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, stylecop

I keep getting these style "errors" when I compile, and I don't want them. I can't find any reference to stylecop on my hard drive, but everything on the web seems to suggest that these errors result from stylecop. How do I turn them off? They suck.

i.e., "SA1121: Use the built-in type alias 'int' rather than Int32 or System.Int32"

Answer (score 0):

StyleCop requires Resharper to work.  Hover over the light bulb for R#, drop down the list of actions that can be done and you should see one for Suppress SA1121.  Make that selection and then you will see a dialog for indicating if this rule is error, warning, hint etc.  Just turn it off there and you should never see that rule again.